# creating a hashmap or set for objects without equals()

Tags: java, equals

I am creating subclasses of a class where `equals()` and `hashCode()` are `final` and based on identity. (Specifically the [XML DOM XOM](http://www.xom.nu/apidocs/) with the contract:

```
public final boolean equals(Object o)

    Tests for Node/Element identity. That is, two Node/Element objects 
    are equal if and only if they are the same object.
```

`Element` is subclassable (e.g.

```
 FooElement extends xom.nu.Element
```

and I use this extensively. I have also developed equality methods (e.g.

```
fooElementA.isEqualTo(fooElementB)
```

which I would like to use in creating sets and hashmaps.

I cannot rewrite the XOM library nor convince the author to release the `equals()` method. Are there generic workarounds (such as wrappers, delegates, subclassing `HashMap`, etc.) that I can use?

NOTE: `hashCode()` is also final.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this were .NET I'd recommend you a [`Dictionary` with a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072.aspx). In Java though you need to wrap your objects into a [*decorator*](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternDecorator.aspx) that implements `hashCode` and `equals`.

```
final class FooElementWrapper {

  private final FooElement inner;
  public FooElementWrapper(FooElement inner) {
    this.inner = inner;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return 0; // replace by a proper implementation!!!
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(o instanceof FooElementWrapper) {
      return this.isEqualTo((FooElementWrapper)o);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

}
```

A `Set<FooElementWrapper>` should do the job now. You should absolutely re-implement `hashCode` with an implementation that works on the public variables of `FooElement`.

Comment: And I can create `int fooElement.createHashCode()`

Comment: I can see that this works. I have ca 100 subclasses so would have to create 100 Wrappers.

Comment: @peter.murray.rust you could create an interface implemented by all your subclasses and wrap that interface (maybe using generics)

Comment: @WilQu yes. This is an attractive way to go.

Comment: @peter.murray.rust Yes, it would be 100 wrappers then. I would personally not worry too much, however, unless it is turning out to become a bottleneck...

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) (or [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)) with your own Comparator.

```
Set<Element> set = new TreeSet<Element>(new Comparator<Element>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Element e1, Element e2) {
        // Your own compare logic
    }
});
```

---

### NOTE

From the docs

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to correctly implement the Set interface.

This means that you are not fulfilling the general contract of equals method.

You can use this method **if and only if** you are really explicit in your documentation about what you are doing.

Comment: Is this effectively the same as @Matthias use of Dictionary/Icomparer (.NET) in his answer?

Comment: @peter.murray.rust I believe so.

Comment: No this is not the same. The Comparator is responsible for element order. As we deal with set, the elements with the same hashcode and equals result will not be included into the structure.

Comment: @Vash You're wrong, they **will** be included. The TreeSet is only using the compare for insertion, hashCode and equals will not be used.

Comment: @maba can I use this method if there is no natural ordering of the Elements? Because I may have A < B and B < C but not necessarily A < C. I am not immediately concerned about performance

Comment: @peter.murray.rust Your comparator is **the** ordering that is going to be used. So you can use this method but having in mind that it breaks the Set contract.

Comment: @maba, No, the TreeSet use compare for order not for insertion. See the [example](http://ideone.com/hyeepe).

Comment: @Vash Please look at the [TreeSet source code](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java.util/TreeSet.java.html) which uses [TreeMap source code](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java.util/TreeSet.java.html). You'll clearly see that it uses the comparator in the put method. Not an equals or hashCode in sight!!!

Comment: @maba, In did it does, and have rational point as it is a Tree it does not have to valid the hash or equals because it can not decide on that on witch site the new element should be placed.